# Multi docker WLS containers on same host, making them accessible to outside world

Tags: docker

I have a docker container running weblogic with some of our applications (EARs) deployed. When each of these EARs start, they register themselves with an external service manager component. At the time of registration, both the host address (using InetAddress) and appPath (from the servlet context) is provided. Thus to the service manager component, the application is available as = http://{hostAddress}:/{appPath}/. When different application consumers want to access the apps, they consult the service manager and get the endpoint.

Now, to get this to work, I had to do one of the following while starting the weblogic container

1. use --net=host option or
2. set --name= and expose weblogic admin port with -p 7001:7001

Only then the app could be accessed from outside. If I don't use any of these options, the {hostAddress} in http://{hostAddress}:/{appPath}/ is replaced with the hostname of the container and the app is then not reachable from outside

But this creates an issue because now I cannot have more than one WebLogic container running on a host. Is there a way to solve this problem in a way that we would run multiple instances of weblogic containers while still allowing the outside world to reach them?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  You have a couple of options:

- You can expose the services on different ports.  For example, if you are running your first contained on host port 7001 (with `-p 7001:7001`), you can expose a second container on port 7002 (`-p 7002:7001`) and so forth.
- You can bind the containers to different host ip addresses.  When you publish ports with `-p`, you can provide a specific host address to which the port should be bound.  The syntax is `-p <ip>:<hostPort>:<containerPort>`, so assuming that your host had both `172.16.1.100` and `172.16.1.101` addresses assigned on an interface, you could start one container with `-p 172.16.1.100:7001:7001` and a second container with `-p 172.16.1.101:7001:7001`.

Comment: It's not enough to map a different port. WebLogic must become aware of the external listen address / port that the application will be listen to in order to properly provide that information back to the application itself. Check the http://github.com/oracle/docker for some WebLogic Script Tool samples. It will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Would it make sense to use a haproxy?  For example, you could train haproxy to run as the first 'weblogic' application on whatever ip:port.  Then, you could create containers in the standard way, exposing random ports.  You could map those ports via the url's path using haproxy. something like:

```
frontend http_proxy
    bind 192.168.1.1:7001
    acl is_app1 path_beg -i /app1
    acl is_app2 path_beg -u /app2

    use_backend app1_server if is_app1
    use_backend app2_server if is_app2

backend app1_server
    mode http
    server app_1 192.168.1.100:7002 check

backend app2_server
    mode http
    server app_2 192.168.1.100:7003 check

...
```

You would expose haproxy on the host side to 7001.  When you add apps, you would need to reconfigure haproxy (i haven't thought that through) but the outside configuration would stay the same.

Using this technique you could create multiple apps bound to the same backend round robin fashion.

-g

Comment: Thanks Greg, I will try experimenting with this option as well.